# How does the Mapping Node work?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, unity, vector-mapping, vector

I am wondering how the mapping node exactly works. The only thing I need to know, is what the individual **Location**, **Rotation** and **Scale** vectors, especially the **Location** vector, do to the input vector.
Does changing the Location vector simply add onto the input vector or is there a more complex approach behind it?
I'm interested in remaking the Mapping node as a part of a shader, which is not related to Blender and I'm not quite sure about that.
I couldn't really answer my question with the posts I found in the internet.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Location does indeed just add to the vector-- using a mapping node that maps location is no different than using a vector math/add node.  Scaling just multiplies the vector's components.  Rotation of 2D coordinates moves your x,y to length * cos (thetaInitial+thetaMapping), length * sin (thetaInitial+thetaMapping).  The only thing that's remotely complicated is the order of those operations-- but then, you can always specify order by doing sequential mappings.

But really, what it's doing is creating a transformation matrix and then multiplying your vectors' positions by that matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix .  The matrix multiplication explains the math behind 3D rotations and the order of operations.

If you're recreating the effect for a shader in, say, Unity, you can just add values to your UV (for example), there's nothing wrong with that.  But there's a lot of value in having at least some understanding of transformation matrices, for writing shaders and for understanding 3D graphics in general.

Comment: Sure, of course. I definitely understand what's going on there. I just wanted to make sure how Blender handles this.
Thank you very much for your answer!